# The file was not create - wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to turn an HTML page into a PDF file. But when calling my function in PHP that does the job of converting the last HTML to PDF, it gives an error.

I tried to create the file in another folder of my project, but without success. I also tried using another version of wkhtmltopdf but I did not succeed, it seems to me that the problem is not in the process of transforming into PDF, but rather in creating the file.

```php
try {
            $pdf = new Pdf('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf', array(
                'page-width' => '150mm',
                'page-height' => '250mm',
                'page-size' => 'A4',
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            ));

            $htmlDecode = base64_decode($param);

            $pdf->setTemporaryFolder('/home/matheus/workspace/app-create-pdf/data');
            if(is_file('/home/matheus/workspace/app-create-pdf/data/generated-boletos/new_boleto.pdf')) {
                unlink('/home/matheus/workspace/app-create-pdf/data/generated-boletos/new_boleto.pdf');
                $pdf->generateFromHtml($htmlDecode, '/home/matheus/workspace/app-create-pdf/data/generated-boletos/new_boleto.pdf');
            } else {
                $pdf->generateFromHtml($htmlDecode, '/home/matheus/workspace/app-create-pdf/data/generated-boletos/new_boleto.pdf');
            }        

            $pdfBoleto = file_get_contents('/home/matheus/workspace/app-create-pdf/data/generated-boletos/new_boleto.pdf');

            $pdfBase64 = base64_encode($pdfBoleto);

            $this->registerInfoCallApi($uri, $param, $pdfBase64);

            return $pdfBase64;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $this->registerErrorApi($uri, $param, $e->getMessage());

            $pdfBoleto = file_get_contents('/home/matheus/workspace/app-create-pdf/data/generated-boletos/new_boleto.pdf');

            $pdfBase64 = base64_encode($pdfBoleto);

            return $pdfBase64;
        }
```

When trying to create the file in the indicated folder, it gives the following error:

```
The file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app-create-pdf\new_boleto.pdf' was not created (command: "C:\www\wkhtmltox\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" --lowquality --page-height "250mm" --page-size "A4" --page-width "150mm" --encoding "UTF-8" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app-create-pdf\knp_snappy5d014377e974c3.34755390.html" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app-create-pdf\new_boleto.pdf").
```

On my computer it works quietly, but putting the project on another machine did not work.

Comment: If you copy that exact command and run it on the command line, does it work?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like something in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app-create-pdf\knp_snappy5d014377e974c3.34755390.html`, since path isn't the same as what's in the error message. Maybe it's trying to load something off-site, or something that's in a directory that doesn't exist on the server?

Comment: For some odd reason, it's trying to access something via the network instead of locally, and it's giving a 301 Moved Permanently HTTP error.